# Cómo desactivar rango de fecha de datepicker de jquery a partir de fecha de inicio y fin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datepicker

He estado consultando en la red pero no encuentro nada que me ayude a relacionar el código PHP con JavaScript para deshabilitar el rango de fecha en los cuales no está disponible una habitación consultado desde MySQL.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahorita

```
var disableddates = ["12-3-2016", "12-11-2016", "12-25-2016", "12-20-2016"];

  function DisableSpecificDates(date) {

   var m = date.getMonth();
   var d = date.getDate();
   var y = date.getFullYear();
   var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;

   for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {


   if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
   return [false];
   } 
   }

   return disableddates;
  }

  $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker").datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
   });
});
```

Sin embargo este código es para fechas especificas no para un intervalo, por ejemplo mi fecha de llegada es el `28/12/2016` y mi fecha de salida es el `31/12/2016`, necesito que se bloqueen esos tres dias con tan sólo el intervalo.

Comment: muestra codigo de como estas haciendo ahora mismo, para poder guiarte a partir de tu código

Comment: Crea un input oculto, cuyo valor sea la fecha obtenida de la base de datos, despues al instanciar el datePicker y asignale el valor del campo  a la opcion `maxDate` o `minDate` (segun sea el caso)

Comment: Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahorita

Comment: Sin embargo este codigo es para fechas especificas no para un intervalo, por ejemplo mi fecha de llegada es el 28/12/2016  y mi fecha de salida es el 31/12/2016, necesito que se bloqueen esos tres dias con tan solo el intervalo

Comment: Listo ya lo elimine, es que soy nuevo jeje

Comment: Aquí lo que logre fue desactivar fechas especificas, pero necesito hacerlo dinámico desde base de datos para los intervalos en los que se encuentre reservada una habitación

Comment: checkea esta pagina http://bjvilory.weebly.com/4/post/2011/2/jq01.html quizas te sirva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> deshabilitar el rango de fecha en los cuales no está disponible una habitación

Lo que debes hacer es primero recuperar las fechas y guardarlas en variables JavaScript:

```
var arrivalDate = moment("<?=$llegada?>", 'DD-MM-YYYY');
var departureDate = moment("<?=$salida?>", 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Segundo, debes **obtener el rango de fechas** entre la fecha de llegada y de salida. Para ésto te recomiendo uses [moment](https://npmjs.com/package/moment).

```
function getDatesBetween(start, end) {
  var dates = [];
  start.add(1, 'days'); // empezamos a contar 1 día después
  while (start < end) {
    dates.push(start.format('DD-MM-YYYY').toString());
    start.add(1, 'days');
  }
  return dates;
}
```

Una vez hecho ésto, debes crear una función que verifique si la fecha actual está incluida entre las fechas a deshabilitar. Esto es necesario para desactivar esas fechas de la UI.

```
function beforeShowDay(date) {
    if (!disabledDates.length) {
    disabledDates = getDatesBetween(arrivalDate, departureDate);
  }
  var currentDate = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  return [disabledDates.indexOf(currentDate.toString()) == -1];
}
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/m4bxrmdu/)

Comment: guzgarcia oye me parece que es muy buena idea esa que me estas dando voy a probar implementarlo, te digo si lo soluciono

Comment: @lucho  si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician). Ya publicaste otras 2 preguntas más a las que no le diste seguimiento

Comment: El fiddle ya no está disponible!